# jQuery autocomplete append selection to div

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to insert a variable within a div (#cityInput) upon jQuery autocomplete selection. What am I doing wrong?

```
var options = ["California", "Seattle", "Portland", "San Francisco"];

 $(function() {
    $("#citySelect").autocomplete({
    source: options,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function() { 
     $('#chooseCity').dialog('close'); 
     $('#cityInput').append('airline');
     },
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you have comma after the last option (`select`).
That probably gives your javascript error. (I would recommend some tool, like firebug, for monitoring errors in javascript)

**edit**
Here's a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/eE6S3/). I enter `Se` in input, click on appeared `Seattle` choice and get alert with the city I selected.
Autocomplete works.

Comment: Thanks. I've very new to jQuery. I fixed the comma, but still trying to insert a selected variable into a div.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma:

```
 },
  ^
```